# jQuery replace is cloning, I need it for Each element

Tags: jquery, regex, string

Tried to add a 'sup' tag to the following.  It works, however its cloning the first price it sees, any ideas why?

```
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
  <span class="PageText_L483n">
     <font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:</b></font>
     <span class="priceis strike">$2,533.31</span> </span>
</font>

<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
  <span class="PageText_L483n">
     <font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:</b></font>
     <span class="priceis strike">$288.00</span> </span>
</font>

<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
  <span class="PageText_L483n">
     <font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:</b></font>
     <span class="priceis strike">$1,055.00</span> </span>
</font>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('font.pricecolor').html(
        $('.pricecolor').html().replace(/\.\d{1,2}/,
            function(a){
                return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
            })
    );
});
```

Comment: I'm using Volusion ^ O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `html()` incorrectly as an iterator. Try `each()` instead. Furthermore, within your blocks you want use `this` to reference the current element. Finally a small optimization for your regex.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('font.pricecolor').each(function() {
        elem = $(this);
        elem.html(elem.html().replace(/(\.\d{1,2})/, '<sup>$1</sup>'));
    });
});
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/teXCc/

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because for every element you request `'.pricecolor'` again. Using `.html()` on it to get its current HTML will return the HTML of the first element always.

You should do something like this:

```
$('span.priceis').html(function (i, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/\.\d{1,2}/,
            function(a){
                return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
            });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghdtu/)

**Note:** Don't use the `font` tag, it is deprecated. You can use a simple `span` instead or any semantically matching element.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be refactored, but the issue is resolved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('font.pricecolor').each(function() {
        $(this).html(
            $(this).html().replace(/\.\d{1,2}/,
                function(a){
                    return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
                })
        );
    });

});
```

You need to specify `this` and not the class again in your nested function.

Answer (score 1):

I think theres a slight misunderstanding here. The selector `font.pricecolor` will select all the font tags you are looking for. However, when you use `.html(value)` to set the HTML contents when a list of objects has been selected, `value` is only calculated for the first item in the list and that value is reused for the rest of the list.

You need to use the `.each` in order to create a new value for each item in the list. Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('font.pricecolor').each(function(i)
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.html().replace(/\.\d{1,2}/,
            function(a)
            {
                return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
            }));
    });
});
```